# How to control custom Android app via Bluetooth custom device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm building a Bluetooth device and would like to make it so that once it's paired with an Android device such as a phone or tablet (eg. Nexus 7) it will be able to interact with a custom app on the Android device in a transparent manner without any prior setup.

For example, the behavior I'm looking for is similar to that of a handsfree headset where once you've done the initial pairing you can push a button on your headset, issue a voice command, and it transmits commands to the phone and the phone does it's thing. I have built a Bluetooth device where when a button is pushed it should be able to immmediately send commands to a custom app on my Android device and the custom app should run and do its thing. This should all happen without putting the Android device into some ready state or having my custom app open waiting for commands; it should all be transparent without the user having to do anything (eg. the Android device could be in my pocket or bookbag).

I am a veteran programmer but very new to Android and Bluetooth and would appreciate pointers in the right direction. I imagine that perhaps I would need to install some service-level app on the Android device to implement my own custom profile and/or intercept the Bluetooth commands but these are just guesses; I'm hoping someone would shed light on the actual process so that I can read up on them in detail. I'm also hoping that the solution is a generic one that would apply across the board but right now I'll take anything I can get lol!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the [Android SDK guide about BT?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: @m0skit0 : The Android SDK provides a Bluetooth Chat custom profile but does not go over specifics such as how a developer is expected to install it on an android device. Can it be installed by a user? Does a user need root access? Or perhaps this requires that I compile and install a custom Android with the service integrated?

Comment: Installing on Android is a standard process, you don't even need to know how it goes, SDK does it behind the scenes. Also AFAIK everything stated on the Android SDK does not need root access. Any application can be installed by a user if it does not require root access.

Comment: @m0skit0 : I did a more extensive search last night and found this [link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_Bluetooth_Profile). In that article is another [link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService) about installing it as a service and in there it states that once you're done "Rebuild the framework/base or android system". Well that sucks! Is there another way for a *user* to install a custom profile on any (relatively modern) Android device or should I answer my own question and link to this article?

Comment: So far no answer to my question but my research thus far is leading me to conclude that there is no way I can register a bluetooth profile on the android and that I would have to hook into it and rebuild the source. Would someone please confirm that my goal of adding a bluetooth profile to an android via an app installed as a service is not possible?

Comment: I don't think you can add a custom BT profile without recompiling the whole thing. This doesn't mean it's impossible though. Good luck with it!